# Show Shell Function in Ubuntu Terminal

Tags: bash, alias, functions

Over the years I've moved away from using aliases to defining functions in a `.functions` file that I source at the time of launching the shell. This works fine, but one feature of `alias` that I miss is being able to see what a particular function does.

Example:

- Alias:

  ```
  alias tailnet='journalctl -f -u NetworkManager'
  ```
- Function:

  ```
  tailnet() {
    # Continuous tailing of the network log
    journalctl -f -u NetworkManager
  }
  ```

In order to see what the alias `tailnet` does, I can just type `alias tailnet` and the definition of the alias will be shown. Is there something similar for functions or do I have to open the file where the function is defined?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do both (*and maybe more*) at once with `type -a` like so:

```
$ type -a tailnet
tailnet is aliased to `journalctl -f -u NetworkManager'
tailnet is a function
tailnet () 
{ 
    journalctl -f -u NetworkManager
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Use `declare`:

```
declare -pf tailnet
```

- `-p` tells declare to print the definitions;
- `-f` tells declare `tailnet` is a function.

Comment: Dude! Beautiful! I learn something every day on this site. Thanks, mate!